# C++ CX - Convert Windows::Storage::Streams::Buffer to Platform::String

Tags: string, type-conversion, c++-cx

If I have some readable data/bytes stored within a Windows::Storage::Streams::Buffer object - what would be the best way to convert this into a Platform::String so that I can pass it to another API?

Is using the static method DataReader::FromBuffer and then using LoadAsync the way to go?

Comment: String is not an especially good type for storing binary data.  Consider getting a byte array first and encoding it (Base-64, for example).

Comment: Unfortunately these types are not chosen by me. I have the data as a Buffer and I need to pass it to another API as a String^ ... so my hands are tied!

Comment: Well, the other API needs to tell you the required encoding.  Or does it just store/transport the data you give it, unchanged?

Comment: We can safely assume that the Buffer contains bytes representing readable ascii

Comment: So you want each byte to become a character (2 bytes) in the String?

Comment: Ok let's take it in a different direction to avoid problems. How about taking each byte, converting the byte to hex, and appending it to a String object...so I end up with a string like "0x13 0x58 0x98". Do you have an example of that?

Comment: Are [these](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh802425.aspx) the examples you're looking for?

Comment: Yes! thank you :) CryptographicBuffer::EncodeToHexString() seems to be what I am looking for. One thing...the result doesn't have leading 0x's - any quick way to add that to the resulting String^ ?

Comment: I'm not aware of any easy way to get the `0x`, sorry.  That would be a good new question though.

Comment: Thanks, asked :) How do I give you credit for this answer?

Comment: By commenting that I should write it as an answer... done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation shows that `CrytographicBuffer` is one of the more useful concrete types that can be used for stream I/O, and it has functions for conversion to/from strings.

[Examples here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh802425.aspx)